# Replying to a client over sockets (UDP) from a different process

Tags: c++, c, sockets, udp

I have a server than is a "command handler" process.  It receives messages over UDP, and delegates the work to do to a different process by communicating to that process through it's published API (whatever IPC mechanism that process employes).  Our system has several cooperating processes.  The result of that API call is then then sent back to the client from the command handler process.

One command is to control a data stream that is generated from another process to the client (a "connect" message).

Should this work?  I send the IP address and port number of the client to the other process, that process creates a new socket, and does a sendto...I've traced through the code and everything looks good, but the client is still blocked on the receive...I know if I do a sendto from the command handler, it gets the response, but not from the new socket.

Here's some example code:

```
#define LEN 10000
char buffer[LEN];
int sfd, nsfd, bread, addrsize;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addrsize = sizeof (struct sockaddr_in);
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons(5200);
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
bind (sfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server, addrsize);
bread = recvfrom(sfd, buffer, LEN, 0, &addr, &addrsize);

/* send IP address and port number through the API to another process */
/* in that other process, I do something like this...addr has the IP
 * address and port in it from above: */

nsfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPROTO_UDP);
sendto(nsfd, buff, bread, 0, &addr, sizeof(addr));
```

SO please help!

Comment: which system linux or Windows ?

Comment: How is the client doing its work?  Is it multihomed?  How does it process the datagram - recv(), recvfrom()?  Does it use connect() - yes you can use it on UDP.

Comment: A sendto - i've tested this part (the server receives the request).  No connect is used

Comment: I accept that you know the server works and the datagram goes out and there are no firewall issues, etc.  My suspicions are with the client and how it is processing its end.

Comment: Thanks Duck - I think I found the culprit - sendto is returning 1 - when I'm trying to send 10512 bytes...setsockopt maybe?
Works when I compile the same server on windows, bypassing command handler (default SO_SNDBUF bigger on winsock than vxworks?)...hmmmm...

Comment: wooh - ok, it was returning 1 because my brackets in a if ((res=sendto...)<len) was off...it was returning the number of bytes sent...and still the receive was blocked on the client.
I now have the client "connecting" directly to the server socket on the same process, and it's working...

Comment: Happy to hear you are making progress but now I am confused.  How does the client know what port to "connect" to?  Is Command process sending it the info?  I don't think there was anything wrong (other than potential security issues) with your original plan aside from the bug.

Comment: client sends "connect message" data to server with sendto on a prescribed port (5200).  server receives connect message from recvfrom, which puts the clients ip and port in addr (see code above).  Server processes "connect message" (puts addr is a list of clients) and replies with a "no error" msg

Comment: a thread is periodically streaming data to the client list with a sendto on the addr.  Only supports one client so far.

Comment: I'm making progress, but it's a hack...the desire is to have the command handler process receive the connect message, augment it with client ip/port, relay it to data process, and have data process stream data.  It only works if I bypass the command handler relay.

Comment: A couple of questions. (1) What mechanism do you use to pass the addr/port to the data streamer?  (2) You are certain this msg gets there intact and is correctly sending data to your client? (3) Do you have control of the client source code?

Comment: 1) I use a local socket.  Reason is (and why I know it works) is that the same streaming code compiles are runs on windows, but streams data from a file instead of from realtime sensors.  There's no command handler on the windows version (no relaying), and it works.
2) yes - breakpoint/watch 3) yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client (or a firewall in between) will likely get confused by receiving the response from a different source port than it sent the request to (as the OS will just pick a random source port for the new socket).

One way around this is to use the SO_REUSEADDR socket option in the server and explicitely bind to the correct port when sending the reply. But that would also have the undesireable side-effect that UDP requests might be redirected to one of the other processes instead of the server.

Another option (if you are using Unix/Linux) is to pass the server socket to the other processes via a unix domain socket (via sendmsg and ancillary data).

Comment: That's what I thought - the reply message's source port has to be the destination port from the original message.  Since the application will only be sending, I don't think I'll have a problem with receiving from the wrong process - I'll try to bind the source port before I send and see if that fixes it - if it does, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Sorry cmeerw, but it might be awhile before I attempt this

Comment: I never did try this, and won't because we switched to TCP...so I'll accept this answer as the best

Answer (score 1):

You should be testing for the error return, something like

```
if((nsfd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPROTO_UDP)) < 0} {
    perror("at socket open");
    // I'd call exit here, probably
}
if(sendto(nsfd, buff, bread, 0, &addr, sizeof(addr) < 0){
    perror("At sendto");
}
```

There's a nice tutorial example [here](http://www.abc.se/~m6695/udp.html).

Comment: what were the error codes then?  The obvious things that could happen are permissions error, a firewall intercepting random UDP packets, and some kind of I/O error at one end or the other.

Comment: Everything was fine up to the sendto (no error codes). So you agree I should be able to open a second socket and reply from a different process?  I don't need to reply from the same socket I "recvfrom"ed?

Comment: No you don't. But since any process can blast data back at your client programs often check to see if they are receiving data from where they sent it. Among several possibilities is the one in which your client is simply tossing the data because your server sub-process is using a different port.

Comment: Seriously, read through that tutorial.  It's also got the code for what you want to do.

Comment: @Charlie - perhaps I wasn't clear in my question - I've seen tutorials like this one before, the question is "can I reply from a new socket opened from a different process, or do I have to reply from the one I "recvfrom"'ed. This example doesn't show the reply from the server